# Read count for multiple files redirect to file

Tags: linux, bash

I have ~500 `fastq.gz` in one directory. I'd like to count the number of reads in the forward files and print the output to a file with the read count and file name. This is the script I have:

`` for f in *read1.fastq.gz; do zcat $f | echo $((`wc -l`/4)) $f; done ``

This prints to the terminal and runs through all the files.

However, I want to redirect it to a text file:

`` for f in *R1_001.fastq.gz; do zcat $f | echo $((`wc -l`/4)) $f > read_count.txt; done ``

The above script only determines the read count for one file and then finishes.

I have also tried:

`` for f in *R1_001.fastq.gz; do zcat $f | echo $((`wc -l`/4)) $f >> read_count.txt; done ``

But that just prints the file name

How do I redirect the output to a file?

Thank you

Comment: Do the redirection at the end: after the `done`. Otherwise you do a single redirection for each loop iteration.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Such a simple fix

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work

```
for f in *read1.fastq.gz; do echo $f;zcat $f|wc -l ; done > read_count.txt
```